# iframe calling parent javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is it possible for me to setup an iframe so it calls a javascript function available in the `window.parent.document` scope?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly, assuming `functionName()` is defined within the parent of iframe, you can do this within your iframe:

```
window.parent.functionName();
```

This will only work though, if both parent and iframe are on the same domain: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Comment: **IMPORTANT**: be sure to check out the more modern approach referenced/updated in the above URL ([window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)).  It has [pretty good support](https://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage).

Comment: And a plus on the @Nate answer is that postMessage method is for cross-origin comunicacion. Direct "functionName" not works in cross-origin context.