# How do I write executable jQuery for a parent JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, iframe-app

I've got two [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) files. This first file sets up variables and writes the contents of another file called `iframe.js`:

```
/* Parent File  */
var aff_id = 2; // Your affiliate ID
var aff_source_id='1'; // Your site ID
var aff_source_subid=''; // Your custom tracking ID
var thankyouUrl = ''; // Leave blank if you don't have a thank you page
var live = 0; // 1 for production
var lead_type = 1; // Auto insurance
document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="'+site+'/api/js/iframe.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'));
```

```
/* Child File */
if(!site) var site='https://leadthis.com';
$(function(){
    var height,width,src = 'http://lead/api/iframe/insurance/auto.php#'+encodeURIComponent(document.location.href )+'?aff_id='+aff_id+'&aff_source_id='+encodeURIComponent(aff_source_id)+'&aff_source_subid='+encodeURIComponent(aff_source_subid)+'&live='+live,
    emarfi=$('<iframe id="appframe" src="'+src+'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"><\/iframe>').appendTo('#emarfi');
});
document.write('<div id="emarfi"><\/div>');
```

I would like to write some executable JavaScript code in this child file to work with the iframed content that is written to the parent file. Is this possible? I tried this:

```
document.write("$(function(){ $('iframe').load(function(){alert('Hello Iframe');})});");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An few advices: stay away from `document.write` whenever you can. Don't use global variables, create your own namespace (object). Learn about AJAX that way you won't need that huge src line and your code will become more obvious an easier to maintain.

Comment: Here's a similar [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477324/iframe-calling-parent-javascript)

Comment: Thanks krg, but I need a solution for cross domains.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://ternarylabs.com/2011/03/27/secure-cross-domain-iframe-communication/). Haven't tried it, but it looks promising.

Comment: That's much closer to what I'm looking for.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've started using Porthole based off krg's comment, and that is exactly what I need.  Thanks.
http://ternarylabs.com/2011/03/27/secure-cross-domain-iframe-communication/