# jQuery iframe parent in firefox not working

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-selectors

It appears that, in firefox, this line of code does not work:

```
iframeWin.refreshImgList();
```

However, that same code above works on every other browser (even IE... GASP!).

iframeWin is the id of the iframe. I am outside the iframe trying to call that function **refreshImgList** thats inside the iframe.

What would i need to add/edit to the code above in order to get it working the same way in FF as it does in all other browsers?

Comment: where did you use this code? inside iframe src's javascript?

Comment: @user10: Its being called from within the iframe. The pageslide is on the main page (outside of the iframe)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477324/iframe-calling-parent-javascript

Comment: @user10: thanks for the link but that did not work. Updated my OP.

Comment: what happened? it should work.. can you create simple fiddle to try?

Comment: @user10 Found the solution! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Found the solution:

```
$("#iframeWin")[0].contentWindow.refreshImgList();
```