# How to call a script in an iframe from the parent page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iframe

I am trying to call a script in an IFrame from the parent page from the code behind. The C# I use to call the function:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    string scr = "document.getElementById('mapframe').contentWindow.addPoint(0, 0);"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), scr , true);
}
```

The iFrame's HTML:

```
 <iframe name="mapframe" id="mapframe" src="Map.html" style="width:100%;height:360px;"></iframe>
```

And the Javascript in the IFrame:

```
          function addPoint(lat, lon) {
              var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: myLatlng,
                  map: map,
                  title: "Hit"
              });
          }
```

However, this causes this error: "Unable to get property 'addPoint' of undefined or null reference". What is causing this error? I have checked to ensure that contentWindow is not null.

Comment: Seems to be similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477324/iframe-calling-parent-javascript

You could call the addPoint() method using the same process and of course security issues might occured (must be same domaine pages).

Comment: That question doesn't really help me much. It is the opposite of what I am trying to do. Both pages are in the same domain. What do you mean by same process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is likely that your iframe is not loaded when you try to call that function

Try the following

```
document.getElementById('mapframe').onload = function() {
    // I prefer frames.mapFrame.addPoint();
    document.getElementById('mapframe').contentWindow.addPoint(0,0);
}
```

Or even

```
<iframe 
     name="mapframe" 
     id="mapframe" 
     src="Map.html" 
     style="width:100%;height:360px;" 
     onload="this.contentWindow.addPoint(0,0)"></iframe>
```

Comment: Nailed it. Exactly the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

once the iframe is loaded then after you can call the function add point.
or you can put the call of this function in `onload` event