# Close mootools dialog from inside of iframe

Tags: javascript, mootools, simplemodal

Q: How to close a mootools dialog from inside an iFrame?

I have the following code to open the dialog box on the parent:

```
window.addEvent("domready", function(e){
/* Modal */
$("mootools_dialog").addEvent("click", function(e){
    e.stop();
    var dlgx = document.getElementById("mootools_dialog").offsetLeft-window.getScroll().x-20;
    var dlgy = document.getElementById("mootools_dialog").offsetTop+window.getScroll().y-400;
    dlgx = (dlgx < 20) ? 20 : dlgx;
    dlgy = (dlgy < 20) ? 20 : dlgy;
    var SM = new SimpleModal({"hideHeader":true,"closeButton":false,"hideFooter":true,"offsetLeft":dlgx, "offsetTop":dlgy });
    var form_check = null;

    SM.show({
      "model":"modal",
      "title":"Title, or empty?",
      "contents":"<iframe src='booking.iframe.php' id='booking_iframe' scrolling='no' /></iframe>"
    });
  })
});
```

It works to call functions from inside the iFrame, like `href='javascript:{parent.book_click();}'` But I cannot find a way to close the mootools window.
What do I need inside the iFrame?
I tryed to call a function in the parent to close the window but could not make any code work.
`<a href="javascript:{parent.close_dialog();}">Close</a>`or 
`parent.SimpleModal.close()` - but no sucess.
 
I have mootools 1.3.2

Comment: duplicate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477324/iframe-calling-parent-javascript

Comment: I saw that post also, and I have no problem calling other functions from inside the iFrame (just added/edited that on my question). But exactly this mootools window I cannot close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're using [SimpleModal](http://simplemodal.plasm.it/) class for custom dialogs. The first thing you should notice is that it doesn't have `close` method. However it has `hide` method which does the job.

But `hide` method cannot be called on global `SimpleModal` class, it should be called on instance (that's your `SM` variable). So you can modify your code like following:

```
window.SM = new SimpleModal({"hideHeader":true,"closeButton":false,"hideFooter":true,"offsetLeft":dlgx, "offsetTop":dlgy });
var form_check = null;

SM.show({
  "model":"modal",
  "title":"Title, or empty?",
  "contents":"<iframe src='booking.iframe.php' id='booking_iframe' scrolling='no' /></iframe>"
});
```

Now you have global variable `SM` with current dialog instance, and now you can call its methods from `<iframe>` without any problems like this:

```
<a onclick="parent.SM.hide()">Close</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! that did the job! appreciate it.